# string split to string array

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string variable Result that contains a string like:

```
"<field1>text</field1><field2>text</field2> etc.."
```

I use this code to try to split it:

```
Result = Result.replace("><", ">|<");

String[] Fields = Result.split("|");
```

According to the many websites, including this one, this should give me an array like this:

```
Fields[0] = "<field1>text</field2>"
Fields[1] = "<field2>test</field2>"
etc...
```

But it gives me an array like:

```
Fields(0) = ""
Fields(1) = "<"
Fields(2) = "f"
Fields(3) = "i"
Fields(4) = "e"
etc..
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `split("|")` is parsing `|` as a regular-expression-or, which on its own will split between every character.

You can regex-escape the character to prevent this from occurring, or use a different temporary split character altogether.

```
String[] fields = result.split("\\|");
```

or

```
result = result.replace("><", ">~<");
String[] fields = result.split("~");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing

```
String[] fields = result.split("\\|");
```

Note that I've used more conventional variable names (they shouldn't start with capital letters).

Remember that the `split` methods takes a *regular expression* as an argument, and `|` has a specific meaning in the world of regular expressions, which is why you're not receiving what you were expecting.

---

Relevant documentation:

- [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)